# trying to install and use Pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install and use Pip, ultimately to install dateutil. I found in another thread that I should write

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

I get the error message "'pip' is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Does this mean I should add something to a path? What should I add, and to what path?

Comment: That means you have to install pip first, did you do that?

Comment: I've downloaded get-pip.py and run it. Is that enough?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should check the Python Scripts directory if there is pip is installed. You can find this at c:\Python27\Scripts\ folder. If pip is there in directory then added the scripts folder path to the environment's PATH. You will be able to execute the pip from anywhere throughout the system.

In other way, if pip is available in your scripts directory then go to scripts directory using "cd c:\puthon27\scripts" and use pip from there.

Also, if pip is not installed then you need to install the same.

Note: Change path as per the OS. Above process I mentioned for Windows OS and Python version is 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on windows:

1. Press the windows button
2. Right click 'computer'
3. Click properties
4. On the left top you see list of stuff, click on advanced system configuration
5. Click system variables
6. Go to path and add: ;c:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts

Change it to your python path, ; is to start a new variable.
Also some things I tell you to click on might have a different (but similar) name, I'm translating this from Dutch that's why :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the **Linux** distro:
- Debian, Ubuntu...:

```
apt-cache search pip
// Will list matching .deb packages
apt-get install exact_name_of_the_package
```

- RedHat, CentOS, Fedora...:

```
yum search pip
// Will list matching .rpm packages
yum install exact_name_of_the_package
```

- OpenSUSE:

```
zypper search pip
// Will list matching .rpm packages
zypper install exact_name_of_the_package
```

All of these have to be installed as root.

In case you're running on **Mac OSX**, you may use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install python # that will install pip as well
```

**Windows** installation is described in here: [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: Arch and apt-get? Wait, what? :) Also, the OP is on Windows

Comment: @Kos, how do you know OP is on Windows?

Comment: "is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: I see, I haven't been using Windows for 2 years, so this message tells me nothing.